# How to add Voting System in Angularjs with $localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

> I want to restrict user to vote only one time for a question using
>   $localstorage.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repat="question in questions"> {{question.text}} 
    <button ng-click="upvote(question)">Vote</button>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$scope.upvote = function(question){
  var votedQuestions = [];
$localStorage.votedQuestions = votedQuestions;
if($localStorage.votedQuestions.indexof(question._id) === -1){

$localStorage.votedQuestions.push(question._id);
 console.log("Thanks for Voting");
}
else {
 console.log("You already voted to this question");
}

}
}
```

it is giving me error like `$localStorage.votedQuestions.indexof` is not a function

and it's not storing multiple questions, it's just updating the question id in localstorage array on other question click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always set your `$localStorage.votedQuestions` to an empty array thus user will always have the possibility to vote to all questions.

Just remove this line and it will works fine

```
 //APP
angular.module('myApp')
    .run(['$localStorage', function($localStorage) {
        $localStorage.votedQuestions = [];
    }])

//Controller
$scope.upvote = function(question) {
    if ($localStorage.votedQuestions.indexof(question._id) === -1) {
        $localStorage.votedQuestions.push(question._id);
        console.log("Thanks for Voting");
    } else {
        console.log("You already voted to this question");
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: $localStorage.votedQuestions.indexof is not a function

Comment: You should initialize you $localStorage somewhere out of the `upvote` function

Comment: how to  initialize? can you explain please?

Comment: `$localStorage.votedQuestions.indexOf` with `Of` instead of `of`